# Python: regex to make a python dictionary out of a sequence of words?

Tags: python, regex

I have a .txt file with the following contents:

```
norway  sweden
bhargama  bhargama
forbisganj  forbesganj
canada  usa
ankara  turkey
```

I want to overwrite the file such that these are its new contents:

```
'norway' : 'sweden',
'bhargama': 'bhargama',
'forbisganj' : 'forbesganj',
'canada':  'usa',
'ankara':  'turkey'
```

Basically I want to turn the .txt file into a python dictionary so I can manipulate it. Are there built in libraries for this sort of task?

Here is my attempt:

```
import re
target = open('file.txt', 'w')

for line in target:
  target.write(re.sub(r'([a-z]+)', r'':'"\1"','', line))
```

I'm succeeding in getting the quotes; but what's the proper regex to do what I described above?

Comment: why do you want to use regex here there is no need of regex here

Comment: First thing that came to mind... Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: will there be only two words separated by space

Comment: Yes, two words with space, followed by a newline character

Comment: do you need a python dictionary (an object in memory: `type(obj) == dict`) or do you need a string that looks like text representation of a dictionary?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, either or would be great.

Comment: `d = dict(line.split() for line in open('file.txt'))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for that.

File:

```
norway  sweden
bhargama  bhargama
forbisganj  forbesganj
canada  usa
ankara  turkey
```

Code:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    my_dictionary = dict(line.split() for line in f)
```

This goes through each line in your file and splits it on whitespace into a `list`. This generator of `list`s is fed to `dict()`, which makes each one a dictionary key and value.

```
>>> my_dictionary['norway']
'sweden'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you don't use `strip()`, the value will have `'\n'` at the end, and I didn't want that.

Comment: I tested it (more than once) and found that it did need the `strip()`. However, I tested it yet again just now and it isn't producing the result I got before. I don't know why the result is different now, but I'll remove it.